# Express request body return null

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I have a problem with `express` `POST` request,

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))


app.post('/movie/add', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body) // {}

  //
})
```

can someone tell me, why after sending some data like:

```
{
    "msg":"Hello"
}
```

then my `req.body` return me `{}`? He should return me an object of my `msg` value but instead of I have an empty array :/

thanks for any help!

Comment: where is the response? there should be `res.json(xxx)` below `const errors = validationResult(req);`

Comment: @MicFung this is not important, why my `console.log` return me `{}`?

Comment: Please show us your full post/image of the program you're posting with

Comment: No error in the code. Are you using `POST` request? any screenshot ?

Comment: @markWanka because your route isnt receiving any data. The problem is probably from you front end

Comment: Please provide client-side code that is sending this data (aka prove that there's actually data)

Comment: @markWanka check your POST request. Please share the details of how you sent the request. The code part is correct and should work. Please test your request by Postman.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things if you want to use the request body.

1.in request header include Content-type  application/json

2.in code Use middleware to parse into json.  app.use(express.json());

```
Note use  ​app.use(express.json()) before route declartion.
```

[view example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oK9ZX.png)

Bydefault body is undefined
app.use(express.json());  help you to defined the data
while content-type application/json allow you to pass json.if you did not include content-type application/json request.body will return define empty object { }.

Answer (score -4):

I think you should use body-parser
http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

Comment: Also, even if it weren’t deprecated, please be sure to provide a basic example of how a library can be used to solve the specific problem, instead of just linking to the library.